# Using \psfrag with \mathcal

Tags: latex, psfrag

I am trying to replace

```
\mathcal{R}
```

in a figure by

```
\left |\mathcal{R} \right |
```

using \psfrag as follows

```
\psfrag{$\mathcal{R}$}{$\left |\mathcal{R} \right |$}
```

However, it doesn't work. Apparently, the stylish R is not recognized. Do you know how can I solve this problem? The `\mathcal{R}` is on an axis and the figure was produced using MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\psfrag{<tag>}{<LaTeX>}` searches for an *exact* use of `\tag`. So, if you have `\mathcal{R}` in your MATLAB figure, you need to use

```
\psfrag{\mathcal{R}}{$\lvert \mathcal{R} \rvert$}
```

not

```
\psfrag{$\mathcal{R}$}{$\lvert \mathcal{R} \rvert$}
```

Note that I'm not using extensible `\left`...`\right` delimiters, as it's not needed here.